# Decode JWT token received from Authorization Code

Tags: jwt, docusignapi

Is there any way to decode (get the payload) of the JWT token received from Authorization DocuSign api via Authorization Code authentication method?

I am trying to use https://jwt.io/ and decode the token with `RS256` algorithm and the secret code for `Authorization Code`.

Comment: if it's a JWT, it should work with jwt.io. Header and payload are just base64url encoded, so you could do it in your program as well. You said "I am trying to use jwt.io" so what's the result? Did it not work? Are you sure you got a JWT then?

Comment: as it is in documentation it is a jwt. I am getting invalid signature

Comment: Sorry, I am not 100% sure if terminology "token" here means jwt: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant

Comment: jwt.io of course needs to know the public key, before it can verify a signature. You need to paste it into the field on the right column.

Comment: I know that, but still when I pass it I recevie invalid signature

Comment: ok, but your question is about decoding the payload. So that part should work, regardless of the signature.

Comment: but it does not

Comment: Then it's probably no JWT. Does it start with "eyJ..." and then 3 segments separated by "."? If not it's nö JWT.

Comment: Yes exactly it looks like that. Starts with ey, 3dots. I am sure it is a jwt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. When you perform the [Authorization Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant) workflow, the Code response you get back from DocuSign is not intended to be decoded as a JWT token.

That code can only be exchanged for an Access Token. It has no other purpose.

Comment: But I already received code and requested for token. I am trying to decode the token, not the code

Comment: The Bearer Token is used in an Authorization header. It is also not intended to be decoded as a JWT token.

Comment: Oh really? So may I ask you what excatly it is? Is there any way to get user or any other information based on access token but with no call to Api?

Comment: No, there is no publicly documented way to pull user info out of the token itself. In order to do so, you'd need to make a UserInfo call: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info ;)