# How do I check my authorization code in authorization code flow?

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, authorization

I am using ADB2C and MSAL to create an authentication function.
And ,Authorization code flow is used.
I know how to check the contents of the token, but I don't know how to check the contents of the authorization code. Please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can not decode the authrization code.

When you perform the Authorization Code Grant workflow, the Code response you get back from authorization server is not intended to be decoded as a JWT token.
That code can only be exchanged for an Access Token. It has no other purpose

You can refer this [document](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/server-side-apps/authorization-code/) for why we use auth codes to reduce the risk of an attacker.

Reference : [Decode JWT token received from Authorization Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57154114/decode-jwt-token-received-from-authorization-code)